# Jquery UI getting value from slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sliders in my page : one with period and the other one with amount. I want to get the values of the sliders every time them are changed, and that values use in another function. Here is my code

**For period slider**

```
        $(function() {
        $( "#slider-period" ).slider({
            range   : "max",
            min : 3,
            max : 12,
            value   : 4,
            slide   : function (event,ui) {
                $(".period").html(ui.value+" years");

            },
            change  : function (event,ui) {
                $(".period").html(ui.value+" years");

            }

        });
    });
```

**For amount slider:**

```
        $(function() {
        $( "#slider-amount" ).slider({
            range   : "max",
            min : 500,
            max : 150000,
            step    : 1000,
            value   : 1200,
            slide   : function (event,ui) {
                $("#amount").html(ui.value+" RON");
            },
            change  : function (event,ui) {
                $("#amount").html(ui.value+" RON");
            }


        });

     });
```

I want to make two global variables that are actualized every time the sliders are changed. Any idea?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a global function that is called whenever they are updated.

```
function sliderUpdated() {
    var periodVal = $( "#slider-period" ).slider("option", "value");
    var amountVal = $( "#slider-amount" ).slider("option", "value");

    //dostuff
}
```

For period slider

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-period" ).slider({
        range   : "max",
        min : 3,
        max : 12,
        value   : 4,
        slide   : function (event,ui) {
            $(".period").html(ui.value+" years");

        },
        change  : function () {
            sliderUpdated();

        }

    });
});
```

For amount slider:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-amount" ).slider({
        range   : "max",
        min : 500,
        max : 150000,
        step    : 1000,
        value   : 1200,
        slide   : function (event,ui) {
            $("#amount").html(ui.value+" RON");
        },
        change  : function () {
            sliderUpdated();
        }


    });

 });
```

Comment: Thaks for reply! When i try to print the values it say is undefined.

Comment: Updated answer to get the slider value properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make two variables at the top of your script and update them from the change method of the jquery slider. For example

```
    var years;
    var amount;

    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-period" ).slider({
            range   : "max",
            min : 3,
            max : 12,
            value   : 4,
            slide   : function (event,ui) {
                $(".period").html(ui.value+" years");

            },
            change  : function (event,ui) {
                $(".period").html(ui.value+" years");
                years = ui.value;
            }

        });
    });

 $(function() {
        $( "#slider-amount" ).slider({
            range   : "max",
            min : 500,
            max : 150000,
            step    : 1000,
            value   : 1200,
            slide   : function (event,ui) {
                $("#amount").html(ui.value+" RON");
            },
            change  : function (event,ui) {
                $("#amount").html(ui.value+" RON");
                amount = ui.value;
            }
        });
     });
```